# Make operations between different numbers of all cells on tableview iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview

I HAVE THIS: A tableview with cells with a label were user gets a number. (From core data from a detail view).

WHAT I WANT: How to make an operation with all the cells with a number on a label on that cell.
Example, sum up all the cells label. label at cell 1, + label at cell 2, and so on.

MY PROBLEM: i can do it but with a lot of code, i have to make an operation for each cell user may create. (Maybe user creates 1 or 20 cells), and i think to make an operation with the index path and value for 20 cells its not necessary.
Im sure its another way but i don't know how.

Thanks from know to everybody.

Comment: For every cell, you have an instance of an entity in Core Data, and that instance has an attribute to hold the number?

Comment: yeap. My entity is call Numbers, and a atribute with the name mynumber. and, obiously, i use that atribute to set the cell "number title label"

Answer (score 0):

So, you have a couple of options, this one is little code but isn't so efficient as the numbers start to add up:

```
NSArray *myNumbers = ...;
```

I'm assuming that this array exists and is being used to drive your table view. It contains the instances of your `Numbers` entity. Based on that, you can get the sum:

```
NSNumber *sum = [myNumbers valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.mynumber"];
```

---

The alternate route is to use `NSExpression` and `NSFetchRequest` to run the summing operation on the entities in the data store without actually reading everything into memory like the array does.

There is also a middle ground option where you could just run an `NSFetchRequest` to get only the `mynumber` values in dictionaries and then use `valueForKeyPath:`. The value of this option depends on how many attributes your `Numbers` entity has and what they contain.